# how can i push a standard variable from an array to calculate a booking day according to specific dates?

Tags: javascript

I have such a piece of code where I get more than one array of variables where I have the start, end and price days; I was able to calculate the value according to the variables when there is no interval between arrays, however when such arrays have an empty date range in the reservation I have to get the default price from a database. The code must be delivered via javascript I thought of several solutions like giving a push in the array but without success.

in short I need to calculate a price divided by dates and deliver the average of that value since they are not always the same follows an example of the result in foreach:

```
const allSeasons = [
      {startDate: new Date (2021, 1-1, 1), endDate: new Date (2021, 4-1,30), costRate: 600},
      {startDate: new Date (2021, 5-1, 1), endDate: new Date (2021, 9-1,30), costRate: 800},
      {startDate: new Date (2021,10-1, 1), endDate: new Date (2021,12-1,31), costRate: 1200}
],
```

Could someone help me find a solution?

Thank you, Luciano Rodrigo

code snippet:

```
if (checkin > 0 && checkout > 0) {
  //Função para determinar o preço sazonal 
  function getPrices(allSeasons, checkin, checkout) {
    const day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    return allSeasons.reduce((precoTotal, season) => {
      let daysInSeason = Math.round(
        (Math.min(+season.endDate + day, checkout) -
          Math.max(season.startDate, checkin)) / day);

      return precoTotal + (daysInSeason > 0 && daysInSeason * season.costRate);
    }, 0);

    console.log(AllSeasons);
  }

  const allSeasons = [
      <?php foreach($this->view->preco_sazonal as $preco_sazonal) { ?> {
        startDate: new Date(Date.parse("<?= $preco_sazonal['startDate'] ?>")),
        endDate: new Date(Date.parse("<?= $preco_sazonal['endDate'] ?>")),
        costRate: <?= $preco_sazonal['preco_sazonal'] ?>
      },
      <?php } ?>
    ],
    checkin = new Date(document.getElementById("checkin").value),
    checkout = new Date(document.getElementById("checkout").value),
    precoTotal = getPrices(allSeasons, checkin, checkout);

  var preco = parseFloat((precoTotal / noites).toFixed(2));
  var moeda_preco = moeda + preco;
  var total = moeda + precoTotal;
```

Comment: Just as a side note, that's not how to inject data into your script from PHP. To ensure proper escaping and quoting, use `json_encode`. E.g. `startDate: new Date(Date.parse(<?=json_encode($preco_sazonal['startDate'])?>))`

Comment: However, this does not look like a PHP question, so I removed the tag. You should show the final rendered JavaScript (view source in browser) and not the PHP code used to make it. You should also show what results you are getting from `getPrices` function, and how they are different from what you expect.